# Linear independence of a span of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Prove: If $B=\{v_1, v_2,...,v_l\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$ and $v$ is not contained in the $span(B)$, then $B\cup\{v\} $ is linearly independent.

Would it be sufficient to extend the basis? It's basically proving the independence theorem but I'm not sure if a proof by contradiction would be better.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to show that $B\cup\{v\}=\{v,v_1,\dots,v_l\}$ is a linearly independent set, so you should recall the definition of linear independence:

> **Definition**: The set $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent if $a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n=0$ for $a_i\in F$ (where $F$ is our scalar field) implies $a_i=0$ for all $i$.

You should more or less try to blindly follow this definition for your proof. That is, suppose

$$a_0v+a_1v_1+\dots+a_lv_l=0$$

for some $a_i\in F$. Then we want to show that all $a_i$ are zero.

Your first step to do this should be to think, "what would happen if $a_0\neq0$?". In this case, you should be able to write $v$ as a linear combination of $v_i$, contradicting the fact that $v$ is not in the span of $B$. This tells you that $a_0=0$, and now use linear independence of $B$ to deduce that the rest of the $a_i$ are zero.

Can you fill in the details here?